# How to force Clickhouse's Kafka engine to check Nested columns length

Tags: clickhouse

I have a Clickhouse server with an `Engine=Kafka` table with Nested fields and `kafka_handle_error_mode='stream',input_format_import_nested_json=1` settings and two materialized views:

- one for `_error=''` case which stores data into underlaying table with same structure as `Engine=Kafka` table
- one for `_error!=''` which stores raw messages and error in case of 'wrong' data

The problem is when clickhouse gets message from kafka with different Nested column lengths (e.g. `{"n":{"a":["1","2"], "b":["3"]}}`) it goes through `Engine=Kafka` table without generating an _error and gets stuck on table insert (and hangs entire save loop) because Kafka table doesn't check Nested columns length but target table does.

There is a `flatten_nested=0` setting which seems to change the Nested behavior but it demands different json structure which is unacceptable for my case. Is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 1):

1. Kafka engine does not check the sizes of nested arrays because it's a limitation of MergeTree table.
2. The structure of Kafka engine is not necessarily to match with MergeTree table. Just add corresponding transformation / check in Materialized View SELECT.

Example:

```sql
create table n ( a Nested( n1 int, n2 int ) ) Engine=Kafka ....;
create table m ( an1 Array(int), an2 Array(int) ) Engine = MergeTree order by tuple();

create materialized view m_mv to m
as select 
     a.n1 as an1, 
     a.n2 as an2
from n;
```

Comment: It feels like there should be a setting to enable the check

Comment: The custom array sizes check in Materialized View does the job. I wonder if it has insert performance impact?

Comment: @YngveStardust No performance impact. The only difference between Nested and Array in this case is the dot "." in the name: "a.n1 Array(int)" vs "an1 Array(int)".

Comment: The existence of this check is a philosophical question. Mostly CH avoids any checks by performance reasons. I always wondered why this check exists at all (in other places CH allows to save garbage in a table, why not in this case).

Answer (score 0):

I am also interested to know if there is a clean/performant way to solve it.

A suggestion that might fit your use case would be to store a string in the Kafka table.
In the materialized view, you can use Json Functions and filter errors ...

```sql
CREATE TABLE kafka(
            payload String
            )  engine = Kafka
SETTINGS  kafka_broker_list = 'localhost:9092',
    kafka_topic_list = 'nested',
    kafka_group_name = 'nested',
    kafka_format = 'JSONAsString',
    kafka_num_consumers = 1,
    kafka_handle_error_mode = 'stream';

create materialized view  consumer
        to valid_payload_table
        as select
               JSONExtract(payload, 'a', 'String') as a, 
               JSONExtract(payload, 'b', 'String') as b,
        from kafka
        where _error!=''
```

Comment: I think JSONAsString solution is not a way to go for my case. If you have Enum in your target table you have to manually check for Enum constraints in where clause. Besides the need to  check array sizes.